# catching Google Maps iOS API key not working exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, maps

Is there a way to get notified inside the app when you provide a wrong key to `google`maps and get this error :

> ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x1818bf40 {data={length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = ...}}

Comment: I dont think there is a way to detect if your api key is invalid or not programmatically. But if you add a `GMSGeocoder` instance variable to your viewcontroller, you app will crash by `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSServicesException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via [GMSServices provideAPIKey:...]`